# Функция вывода не выводит символы, Ассемблер

Tags: ассемблер, nasm

Я новичек в ассемблере, пытаюсь написать функцию, выводящую символы на экран на виндовс:

```
_print:
    ; rdi - stroke
    ; ebx - lenght
    sub  rsp, 40
    mov  rcx, -11
    call GetStdHandle
    mov  rcx, rax
    mov  rdx, rdi
    mov  r8d, ebx
    xor  r9, r9
    mov  qword [rsp + 32], 0
    call WriteFile
    add  rsp, 40
    ret
```

когда я в нее передавал напрямую переменные:

```
mov rdx, message
mov r8d, lenght
```

все работало, но когда я решил делать это через регистры, функция не выводила на экран ничего. Может быть проблема в выбранный регистрах?

В дополнение скажу что убрав `ret` функция стала бесконечно выводить строку

Comment: Не помню точно, но вроде соглашение вызова не гарантирует, что вызываемая функция (GetStdHandle в данном случае) не затрет тот же rdi. Можно проверить это отладчиком. А вообще - делайте получение хэндла один раз при старте программы, сохраните в глобальную переменную. Дальше просто используйте. Ну и передавать параметры в вашу процедуру можно через те же rdx, r8d. Останется вопрос, зачем вообще нужна отдельная процедура, если в ней будет только вызов WriteFile.

Comment: как я понял, в переменную нужно сохранять значение из ```rax``` (```mov rcx, rax``` в функции), но как это сделать? Я пробовал ```mov desc, rax``` и ```mov [desc], rax```, но все равно не работает. (desc - переменная)

Comment: `mov [desc], rax` - вот так должно работать, переменная должна быть объявлена как dq.

Comment: ( ._.)
output.o:output.asm:(.text+0x49): relocation truncated to fit: IMAGE_REL_AMD64_ADDR32 against `.data'

Comment: Нужно весь код смотреть. По этому куску нельзя определить что вы пытатесь сделать за его пределами. Плюс добавьте как компилируете.